# Creating a stored determinant in a Mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

How to create a stored determinant that takes first name, last name, patronymic and phone number as input parameters and returns its id.

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";



CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` int(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `imia` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `familia` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `otchestvo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `telephon` varchar(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



INSERT INTO `employee` (`id`, `imia`, `familia`, `otchestvo`, `telephon`) VALUES
(4, 'Kate', 'Qwerty', ' Asdfgh', '89293781014'),
(5, 'Денис', 'Матвеев', 'какоето', '700000000'),
(12, 'Валерий', 'Жмышенко', 'Альбертович', '700000228');


ALTER TABLE `employee`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `employee`
  MODIFY `id` int(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=13;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stored determinant"? Do you mean a stored function?

Comment: FYI, there little point in using a transaction in the above code. DDL statements automatically commit.

Comment: Isn't the patronymic part of the last name? Why would that be a separate parameter?